# SparkSession close cause endless block

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a java spark application(using spark-sql_2.11 2.1.1) load and cache data from hbase,after some process then insert into hive table, after that, finally close this spark session, but sometimes this application blocked when calling `SparkSession.close()`, after some study on its thread dump,I found a lock involved SparkSession and Spark's `ContextCleaner`,below is the stack snippet:

```
    "pool-4-thread-4" #698 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000070c6000 nid=0x5075 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fcc4a0cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.stop(ContextCleaner.scala:142)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000dc2f6d90> (a org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$4$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(SparkContext.scala:1817)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$4$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(SparkContext.scala:1817)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$4.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1817)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1816)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.stop(SparkSession.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.close(SparkSession.scala:673)
    at a.b.c.d.e.Job$1.done(Job.java:21)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Spark Context Cleaner" #2585 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000023eef800 nid=0x1b66 waiting on condition [0x00007fcc5597e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e36ce078> (a scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$CompletionLatch)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeBroadcast(BlockManagerMaster.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unpersist(TorrentBroadcast.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.unbroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.unbroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.doCleanupBroadcast(ContextCleaner.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:185)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:185)
    - locked <0x00000000dc2f6d90> (a org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:73)
```

as you can see, Spark `ContextCleaner` hold `0x00000000dc2f6d90` and wait for `result,state:TIMED_WAITING`, but it never escaped(after several days), it cause `SparkSession.close` `BLOCKED(waiting to lock <0x00000000dc2f6d90>)`.

below is my close code snippet:

```
    SparkSession session = null;
    Dataset<Row> hBaseCache = null;
    try {
        session = initSparkSession();
        //cache hbase dataset
        hBaseCache = cacheHBaseData();
        //dosomething
        hBaseCache.map(...);
        hBaseCache.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("xxx_hive_table");
    } finally {
        if (hbaseContent != null) {
            hbaseContent.unpersist();
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

seems `unpersist()` before `sparkSession.close()` starts the the `ContextCleaner` and it's `TIMED_WAITING` didn't work...
my application use default Rpc timeout `("spark.rpc.askTimeout", "spark.network.timeout"), "120s")`

please share your opinions about this issue

conclusion:case closed
sorry for your time,my bad,I was too hasty to check the code,turns out someone from Ops override production env's Rpctimeout to a very large value...

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: It caused by a miscommunication between me and Ops team,someone from Ops override production env's Rpctimeout to a very large value